# Application of Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that set of all polynomials are dense in $C(X,R)$, where $X$ is a closed and bounded subset of Real line.

Comment: what is the version of the weierstrass theorem you intend to use?

Comment: $X$ is not necessarily an interval, right?

Comment: yes..it is any closed and bounded set of R

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to notice that every closed and bounded subset $X$ of $\Bbb R$ is included in a segment $S = [a,b]$ and that every function $f \in C(X,\Bbb R)$ is the restriction of a function $\tilde{f} \in C(S,\Bbb R)$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem).

Indeed, the conclusion then follows from the Weierstrass theorem on $S$ and the fact that
$$
\sup_{x \in X} |h(x)-g(x)| \leq \sup_{x\in S}|h(x)-g(x)|
$$
for any functions $g,h : S \to \Bbb R$.

Comment: Weierstass approximation theorem for a given positive value,for every f€C([a,b]),there exists a polynomial p such that distance(sup norm) between f and p is less than that positive value

Comment: The Cantor set is compact but not a countable union of disjoint segments, is it? In fact, it contains no non-degenerate intervals.

Comment: @lhf: actually this is true because of this https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Open_Sets_in_Real_Number_Line.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: There are some equivalent statements of the set $A$ is dense in the set $B$.

Set $A$ is dense in the set $B$.

iff $A \subseteq B \subseteq \bar{A}$ (closure $A$).

iff $\forall \epsilon > 0 $, and $\forall b \in B$, $\exists a \in A$, $\ni |a-b|<\varepsilon$.

iff $\forall b \in B$, $\exists \{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subseteq A$, $\ni \{a_n\} \to b$.

So, let $f \in C(X;\mathbb{R})$, $\varepsilon>0$. Find $g \in C(X;\mathbb{R})$, such that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\varepsilon$, $\forall x \in X$.